# kendo ui grid grouping case insensitive

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to group with kendo grid, but I am facing a problem with the default functionality of kendo grouping. Kendo grid groups the columns but it doesn't differ records of "USA" with "usa", these records come with two different grouped sets of records. Same goes for countries or names like "Washington" and "Washington". I would like to have a case insensitive grouping("USA" amd "usa" means the same logically apart from their case), anyone has any idea on how to do it. I couldn't find this anywhere on kendo documentation.

Here is my code snippet.

```
Maplytics_jQ19("#grdData").kendoGrid(
                        {
                            editable: false,
                            sortable: true,
                            filterable: true,
                            //dataSource: _recordsInGrid,
                            groupable: true,
                            dataSource: {
                                data: _recordsInGrid,
                                group: { field: groupingField }
                            },
                            reorderable: true,
                            resizable: true,
                            dataBound: onDataBound,
                            selectable: false,
                            columns: columns,
                            schema: {
                                data: "_recordsInGrid"
                            },
                            scrollable: true
                        }
                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I override groupBy method in Kendo.data.QUery and it works:

```
    function groupValueComparer(a, b) {
    if (a && a.getTime && b && b.getTime) {
        return a.getTime() === b.getTime();
    }
    if (typeof a == "string" && typeof b == "string") {
        return a.toLowerCase() == b.toLowerCase();
    }
    return a === b;
}
    var isEmptyObject = $.isEmptyObject;

    kendo.data.Query.prototype.groupBy = function(descriptor) {
        if (isEmptyObject(descriptor) || !this.data.length) {
                return new Query([]);
            }

        var field = descriptor.field,
            sorted = this._sortForGrouping(field, descriptor.dir || "asc"),
            accessor = kendo.accessor(field),
            item,
            groupValue = accessor.get(sorted[0], field),
            group = {
                field: field,
                value: groupValue,
                items: []
            },
            currentValue,
            idx,
            len,
            result = [group];

        for(idx = 0, len = sorted.length; idx < len; idx++) {
            item = sorted[idx];

            currentValue = accessor.get(item, field);
            if(!groupValueComparer(groupValue, currentValue)) {
                groupValue = currentValue;
                group = {
                    field: field,
                    value: groupValue,
                    items: []
                };
                result.push(group);
            }
            group.items.push(item);
        }
        return new kendo.data.Query(result);
    }
```

[link demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/evAbAl)